# how to make this animation in flash

Tags: flash, animation

I'm building a web site for a client.
He asked me to make an animation on the homepage to show at start a world image / a globe (just the company logo) that "expands", like if it opens (from behind) into a plain map (which is another image) of the world and then show a text over it.
Now.. I know and develop in PHP / MYSQL / Photoshop / JQuery effects/plugin but sadly (are we sure ? :P ) I know nothing about flash and actionscript.

So I was wondering if you could guide me to what to do, where should I start?
Consider I video edit since 2003ish so I'm not lost here, I was thinking making a video about it and the show it on the page but doesn't feel like a good solution considering that the last frame should be static and more importantly the file size!. Is at least possible to do it in Flash?

I have an advantage over this situation though: I learn fast, so speak up :) what should I do?

Comment: Please be sure this isn't obsctructive, as in only for asthetics. Make sure people can use this website without having flash installed, as a huge amount of people do not have flash now with the advent of smart phone browsers.

Comment: of course I will, anything this is just an animation, nothing to click on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ever edited in After Effects before, using Flash is very similar.  Sounds like you know what you need to do, so open Flash and hop to it!  I'm sorry if this seems like a useless answer, but your question is vague, and you already have the skills needed to get started.

Also, thank you for not making this one huge video.

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer code-like style:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=transitions_3.html

http://code.google.com/p/tweener/